How to connect to password authorized SFTP server using java code. JSCH lib throws "com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail" error
I need  write  Java code to  connect to  sftpuser/sftp_password authorized SFTP server . JSCH lib throws com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail" error. I know the jsch 0.1.55 is no longer maintained. Can you point any other open source library which can fulfill the requirement
              import com.jcraft.jsch.*;
import java.io.InputStream;
public class CustomSFTPConnect
 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sftpHost = "your_sftp_host"; // replace with your SFTP host
        String sftpUser = "your_username";   // replace with your SFTP username
        String sftpPassword = "your_password"; // replace with your SFTP password
  

        JSch jsch = new JSch();

        try {
            Session session = jsch.getSession(sftpUser, sftpHost, 22);
          
            session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setPassword(sftpPassword);
            session.connect();

            Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
            channel.connect();

            ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;

            sftpChannel.exit();
            session.disconnect();

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


                             


+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Below is the error I am facing+++++++++++++++++++++++ 
                   This is in exception when calling runProgram ---------------------------------------->com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.receive_kexinit(Session.java:590)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:320)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)       


This question is similar to: Not able to connect to sftp : com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I had already tried the solution but this solution did not work in my case, I am using JSCH lib 0.1.55

what is your sftp server ? jdk version ?

I would start to with updating to a recent version 0.2..20 Sep 17, 2024 https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.mwiede/jsch

(1) OpenJDK Temurin-17.0.11  (2) jsch 0.1.55 or  0.2.20, (3) ubuntu 20.04 SFTP Server.  (4) use your code is OK, no error message.
